# Fail to use Screen('Preference') in PsychToolbox for MATLAB

Tags: matlab, psychtoolbox

In PsychToolbox for MATLAB, I try to put

`Screen('Preference', 'SyncTestSettings', maxStddev = 0.001, minSamples = 50, maxDeviation = 0.1, maxDuration = 5);`

in the MATLAB command window, but it keeps to tell me:

```
Error in function Preference:   Extra input argument described
Error using Screen
Usage:
 
oldPreferenceValue = Screen('Preference', preferenceName,
[newPreferenceValue])
```

I was confused. The document given by PsychToolbox is:

```
[maxStddev, minSamples, maxDeviation, maxDuration] = Screen('Preference',
'SyncTestSettings' [, maxStddev=0.001 secs][, minSamples=50][,
maxDeviation=0.1][, maxDuration=5 secs]);
```

Is there anything I misunderstand the document? And what is the correct command?

(My MATLAB is R2021a, and PsychToolbox is 3.0.17.12)

Comment: This isn't valid MATLAB syntax, you can't have `=` statements in-line as function call arguments. I suspect the documentation is trying to articulate the order of the inputs and their default values, but the valid syntax is likely just providing the values in the right order.

Comment: @Wolfie, if I remember correctly from 2021 (a? b?) the name=value syntax is allowed in Matlab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish can be done with the following command:

```
Screen('Preference', 'SyncTestSettings', 0.001, 50, 0.1, 5)
```

You have to provide these values in the correct order. If you wanted to skip over a value (i.e., leave it as is) then use

```
[]
```

like so:

```
Screen('Preference', 'SyncTestSettings', 0.001, [], 0.1, 5)
```